# Font issue in Swing application on Mac OS

Tags: java, swing, fonts

In my `Swing` Application, I have a `Label` with font type of [Mistral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistral_%28typeface%29), which works fine in `Windows` but not on `Mac OS X`. Due to that, font size is set to default, which makes clumsy UI. I mean if `Font Name` is unknown then it should atleast consider the given font size. But Font object itself is not created as I am passing invalid font family. So Is there any way to include this `Font`, while packaging jar?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It looks like the Swing resorts to using Swing default font setting for that component when it can not find the font or its substituted font (for example Helvetica in Mac is equivalent to Arial in Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So Is there any way to include this Font, while packaging jar?

Sure, put in in the Jar then get an URL using `getClass().getResource()`.

Look in the [`Font` methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#method_summary) for the `createFont()` variants to load it.

Comment: @eee  True.  OP: Check the license first.